# how to meter an SSH network usage?

Tags: linux, ssh, bandwidth-measuring

It may be a simple question, but how can I see how much bandwidth an SSH connection, in Unix and Linux, has consumed since the login time until the SSH session is terminated (logged out)?

Thanks,
Elias

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run `ssh` with at least one `-v` option, and when you log out you will get something like:

```
Transferred: sent 4288, received 4428 bytes, in 2.7 seconds
```

Comment: That should do, thanks! Will verbose mode slow down SSH (as debug prints are enabled)? Any other generic way that applies not only to SSH? Thanks!

Comment: No, it doesn't slow down anything. You only get output during connection setup and teardown.